# setCentralWidget not declared in scope

Tags: qt, qt4

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include "notepad.h"

notepad::notepad()
{
    textField = new QTextEdit;
    setCentralWidget(textField);
    setWindowTitle(tr("The building of a notepad...."));
}
```

This is a file of one of my Qt project. There is some error with the setCentralWidget part. The error is that it is not declared in the scope. But I have included the QWidget class under which it gets included. What is the mistake?

Comment: What is `notepad` derived from? AFAIK `setCentralWidget(..)` is only available for `QMainWindow`.

Answer (score 3):

`setCentralWidget` is a method on `QMainWindow`.  It is not a top-level function.  It would only be in scope here if your `notepad` class derives from `QMainWindow`, which I guess it must not.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, `setCentralWidget(..)` is only a member of [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmainwindow.html). I think the behavior you are looking for can be achieved by adding a layout to your [QWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html) and then adding your [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtextedit.html) to the layout. I would suggest a [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qplaintextedit.html) as it is setup for editing multiple lines of a text document. [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtextedit.html) is usually used for single line input. Here's some sample code:

```
notepad::notepad()
{
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QPlainTextEdit *textBox = new QPlainTextEdit();
    layout->addWidget(textBox);
    this->setLayout(layout);
    setWindowTitle(tr("The building of a notepad...."));
}
```

The layout can be a [QVBoxLayout](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qvboxlayout.html), [QHBoxLayout](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qhboxlayout.html), [QGridLayout](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgridlayout.html), etc. It all depends on what you want to achieve with the layout of the form. You can also add to your existing layout by using `this->addWidget(QWidget*)` instead of using a newly created layout. I hope this helps.